# Fill an html table cell with div

Tags: html, css

I have a rowspanned table cell with a div inside. I would like to make the div 100% high of the cell.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/gborgonovo/zqohw286/2/

In the example I want the red div vertically fill the yellow cell.

Any hint, please?

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" style="background-color: yellow;">
        <div style="background-color: red; width: 200px; height: 100%;">
          Some text
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="background-color: lightgreen; width: 200px;">
        Row 1.1<br /> Row 1.2<br /> Row 1.3
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="background-color: lightblue; width: 200px;">
        Row 2.1<br /> Row 2.2<br /> Row 2.3
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: can you explain more

Comment: If you want it to completely fill the cell, why don't you simply apply the background color (red) to the cell/td?

Comment: @Johannes I do not use the color in the cell because i need the div inside it, to add for example the border, keeping some space from the cell's edges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<table style="height: 100%;">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td rowspan="2" style="background-color: yellow;">
            <div style="background-color: red;width: 200px;height: 100%;">
               Some text
            </div>
         </td>
         <td style="background-color: lightgreen; width: 200px;">
              Row 1.1<br />
              Row 1.2<br />
              Row 1.3
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td style="background-color:lightblue; width:200px;">
              Row 2.1    <br /> 
              Row 2.2    <br /> 
              Row 2.3
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: use parent table height 100%.  Then it will work perfectly https://jsfiddle.net/sanchit/0ysavtj9/1/

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for.

Comment: @GiorgioBorgonovo Remember to flag the Sanchit's answer as the right answer. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

your div style should be :

```
<div style="background-color: red; width: 200px; height: 110px; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center">Some text</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Then the red cell cannot grow if the green or blue cell grow, isn't it?

Answer (score -1):

I added a class for centered content.

**EDIT**

Based on your comment I made it interactive on [JSFiddle (link)](https://jsfiddle.net/p1a62nbc/1/).

```css
td[rowspan] {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}

.fill {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.centeredContent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;      /* Vertical */
  justify-content: center;  /* Horizontal */
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" style="background-color: yellow;">
        <div class="fill centeredContent" style="background-color: red; width: 200px; height: 100%;">
          Some text
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="background-color: lightgreen; width: 200px;">
        Row 1.1<br /> Row 1.2<br /> Row 1.3
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="background-color: lightblue; width: 200px;">
        Row 2.1<br /> Row 2.2<br /> Row 2.3
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What's wrong with my answer? A `-1` would deserve a motivation. Did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: It's not by me. Anyway I prefer sanchit Dubey answer because it is simpler without using "position: absolute"